# How to convert a calculator to be in degrees?

Tags: calculator

I have a calculator, specially the **Casio fx-9750GII**,but there is a "*slight*" error...

When I put in, for example cos (76

I get the answer in radians.

So, naturally as anyone that's not lazy would do I converted to degrees (instead of buying a new one :] ) and I got the right answer, but everyone gets lazy sometimes, and I was wondering how to just set the calculator to degrees, if that is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a mathematics question.  Most calculators that I know have a button to switch between degrees and radians.  If not, get used to multiplying by $\frac \pi{180}$.  And note, the answer is not in degrees or radians, the input is.

Comment: @RossMillikan Alright, thanks! Where should I put this question instead?

Comment: Try searching for "Casio fx-9750GII degree mode" first.

Comment: @copper.hat I actually figured it out! Check out my answer but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting you calculator

Shift 9 (CLEAR) then press 1 to clear setup

hopefully this will default to degrees

OR

Simply press :
SHIFT Mode (next to ON key)
Then choose '3' for Degrees

BUT I just checked out your calculator online and I think it is different from mine

I think for yours, press SHIFT MENU for the SET UP and then choose Degrees?

hope this helps!

Comment: Hey... did you see my answer (*whisper copycat)? Haha alright thanks!

Comment: Hah no, I just searched up your calculator version and figured myself too

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure **yt.**'s answer works on most calculators, but on the **Casio fx-9750GII** you need to click **shift then menu then scroll down to angle and click f1**

Hopes this helps!